# d3 importing external .SVG files and bind them to objects for functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Exactly like this (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) but calling the data from an external .svg file drawn from Inkscape instead.

Here is my code so far (using Laravel):

```
<script>
  // Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
  var chartDiv = document.getElementById("vis");
  var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
  var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

  // load the external svg from a file
  d3.xml("{{ asset('assets/groundfloor.svg') }}", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
  var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
  d3.select("div#vis")
    .each(function() {
      this.appendChild(importedNode);
    })
    // inside of our d3.xml callback, call another function
    // that styles individual paths inside of our imported svg

    styleImportedSVG(); //calling the zoom feature from a function (it can be called here too)


  });
```

Yes, I have looked it up everywhere on the web for the last few days browsing through multiple blocks and none have yet to make a sample on external .svg files and how to append the elements inside it and assigning it to objects.

EDIT: To be clear, I wanted to know the external .svg file variation of `.data(importedNode.feature(us, us.objects.buildings).features)`  and if that's the only thing I need to change in order to bind the elements in my svg file to objects for d3 functions.

Comment: You have seen Mike Bostock's [*External SVG*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829), right? Since your code is using D3 v3, there is an earlier [revision](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829/30cbd2d7aed891440e289cad45e8cd08c6b9cb94) covering that version, too. Given that it works in both versions of D3, what is your question?

Comment: I've already shown I was able to call an external SVG in my code above which you are answering to. I'm asking how to take the "rect"(s) from my svg file and bind them in objects stated in my EDIT. I've tried .data(ImportedNode.features(us... but obviously it wouldnt work since thats topjson syntax.